# AngularFire OAuth with Google business email

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I want to create a AngularJS WebPage with Firebase where login should be limited to Google business users not google mail in general. How can I check in Firebase or Google, that the login is from a business email domain?

Comment: Now its possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain/38019847#38019847