# Using firebase's google auth but only letting certain emails through

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm working on an application that's accessible to certain users who want to be able to login using their google account. So I'm using firebase as the backend and I'm trying to find out a clean way of letting certain users login based on their email addresses.

Assuming that I'm able to sign up those users and I have them in my firebase's users table, how can I work with permissions to enable only these users to have access to the app?

Comment: You'll have to set up your security rule to enforce access for users that meet your criteria. You can catch that error client side and show the relevant error message.

Comment: @bojeil any doc on how to do that?

Comment: Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030510/restrict-firebase-users-by-email