# How to to logged in users that has verified email only

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I have a function that enable user to sign up or create an account. It also sends verification after signing up. I only want users whose email were verified to logged in.What would I do?

This is my login function.

```
   function signIn() {
   var email = $("#emailtxt").val();
   var password = $("#passwordtxt").val();
   var auth = firebase.auth();        

   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
   password).then(function(value) {
      //NEED TO PULL USER DATA?                     

      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      if(user){
        console.log(user.uid);
        $("#popup").click();
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
   // Handle Errors here.
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message;
   if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
     alert('Wrong password.');
   } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
});
     }
```

Comment: There is no way to require users to have a verified email address before logging in. Instead you'll want to ensure that only users with verified email addresses have access to the resources you're trying to protect. For example, with the Firebase Database you'd do that in its server-side security rules as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019847.

Comment: okay, I'll try your advice sir. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! it works.. I tried both of your suggestions..Thanks for helping.

Comment: Good to hear Camille!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can console.log your current user

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(user); //there you can see emailVerified boolean object will be available.
if(user.emailVerified){
   // then you can allow your users to be logged in your site.

}
else if(!user.emailVerified){ //send a emailverification mail to the user
  firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
    alert('Email Verification Sent!');
  });

}
```

[image: added a picture of user mail verified or not]

Comment: Yes, I can see now in  the console if the user is verified or not and disabled the user to login if its not verified. Thank you by the way. You're a great help.