# Sync Firebase accounts with G Suite accounts

Tags: firebase, google-workspace

I'd like to create an internal app for company's employees with G Suite account. Is there a way to auto-sync Firebase accounts with G Suite accounts?

My main requirement is a way to display to each employee a list of all other employees as a part of the app's GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in for that, but you could write code to auto-create the users from your GSuite domain in Firebase through the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin).

I just wonder what you'd do with those users on the Firebase side. The more common approach is to just let them sign in to Firebase with any account, and then [restrict access based on them being from your (verified) gsuite domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain).

Comment: I read about the approach you suggested and I don't think it's enough. How can that help me show a user all the company employees in the app? Even users that didn't sign up manually. Maybe another approach like accessing Google Contacts of a Firebase user can do?

Comment: There is no API to list the users in Firebase Authentication from the client anyway. You'll want to store the list of users somewhere else for that, typically in a database like Firebase' Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore.