# Can I authenticate users using firebase only with a specific email? Rules of firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to know what should be the rules in firebase to implement this? Suppose I just want to authenticate if the user email is **thisIsExampleEmail@gmail.com**  and no other users can read and write the data of firebase firestore.

**Firebase Rules**

```
allow read, write:if request;
```

what else to add in this to implement the above

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to read the email from? Or do you just want to hard code that single email? The email of user trying to read/write data can be found in `request.auth` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I lock down Firebase Database to any user from a specific (email) domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain)

Comment: Thanks, @Dharmaraj but i have already used it, this is not working. I am not able to read my data

Comment: I'm unsure what rules you've tried. Can you update your question with the same ?

Comment: @Kundan I looked into it but I think the database used there is not cloud firestore but there it's real-time database.

Comment: @Dharmaraj this is the line of code I tried - `allow read, write:if request.auth.email == "myemail@gmail.com";`

Comment: It's `request.auth.token.email` and not `request.auth.email`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks its working now. But to read the data I have to refresh the page again. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Unsure what page you are referring to. I'd recommend posting a new question if that's not related with this question.

Comment: I mean the website page on which I am using this authentication (using reactjs).